# Terminology vs definition tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that there are two tags here that potentially apply to a question that solicits definition(s) and/or clarification of terminology.

- terminology - For questions about clarifications of economics terms. Use this tag to ask about unclear or ambiguous terms. [...]
- definition - Questions about how economic terms, quantities, or ideas can be defined.

It seems there's substantial overlap between these two tags. Can someone clarify (e.g. with some examples) when one tag should be used vs the other? Or maybe they should be merged?

Answer (score 5):

It's a good question. It looks to me like the tags should be merged. Let's see if a dissenting opinion emerges, otherwise I can create the appropriate tag synonym.

Comment: I would second making a tag synonym for these two tags.

Comment: I have performed the merge, replacing `terminology` with [tag:definition]. I did the merge this way around because it looked like pretty much all "terminology" questions referred to definitions, but the converse was not true.

Answer (score 4):

I have no objection per se to merging the two. That being said I would consider definition a sub-category of terminology.

Moreover, definition to me implies more (mathematical) formality, e.g. "we define gross national product as the sum of the value of all final goods and services produced in a country", whereas terminology can be more descriptive, e.g. "inflation are price increases over time."